# What's wrong when VLC says "cannot find hdrl or movi chunks"?

Tags: video, bittorrent, codecs

I BT-downloaded an avi movie "Gintama 2017.avi". I want to play it but I fail.

`ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[avi @ 0x1983d00] Something went wrong during header parsing, I will ignore it and try to continue anyway.
[mpeg4 @ 0x1984ba0] time_increment_bits 0 is invalid in relation to the current bitstream, this is likely caused by a missing VOL header
[mpeg4 @ 0x1984ba0] time_increment_bits set to 4 bits, based on bitstream analysis
[mpeg4 @ 0x1984ba0] looks like this file was encoded with (divx4/(old)xvid/opendivx) -> forcing low_delay flag
[mpeg4 @ 0x1984ba0] warning: first frame is no keyframe
[mpeg4 @ 0x1984ba0] I cbpy damaged at 0 0
[mpeg4 @ 0x1984ba0] Error at MB: 0
[mpeg4 @ 0x1984ba0] marker does not match f_code
    Last message repeated 32 times
[mpeg4 @ 0x1984ba0] concealing 1125 DC, 1125 AC, 1125 MV errors in P frame
Input #0, avi, from './Gintama 2017.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.3 | www.virtualdub-fr.org || (build 2550/release)
  Duration: 00:53:34.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2087 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 720x400, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
```

Conversion:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 'Gintama 2017.avi' -c copy -f matroska 'Gintama 2017.mkv' &> ./ffmpeg.result
[matroska @ 0x1278fe0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 317353, current: 317339; changing to 317353. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 0x1278fe0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 317371, current: 317357; changing to 317371. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

[...]

[matroska @ 0x1278fe0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 366081, current: 366067; changing to 366081. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 0x1278fe0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 366099, current: 366084; changing to 366099. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   20302kB time=00:06:06.14 bitrate= 454.2kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:20020kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.408118%
```

`ffprobe` after conversion

```
ffprobe version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x71bd00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg4, none, 720x400): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Gintama 2017.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:06:06.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 454 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, none, 720x400, SAR 1:1 DAR 9:5, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:00.000000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:06:06.148000000
```

OS

```
$ uname -a
Linux darren-HP-Pavilion-Notebook 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed
Sep 13
09:02:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`file`:

```
$ file ./Gintama\ 2017.avi 
./Gintama 2017.avi:
RIFF (little-endian) data,
AVI, 720 x 400, 23.98 fps,
video: XviD,
audio: Dolby AC3 (6 channels, 48000 Hz)
```

`vlc -vv` output

```
$ vlc -vv
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[0000000001b11098] core libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.2.2 Weatherwax
[0000000001b11098] core libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2016 the VideoLAN team
[0000000001b11098] core libvlc debug: revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80

[...]

[0000000001b11098] core libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX FPU 
[0000000001bdf058] core input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[0000000001bdf058] core input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options

[...]

[00007f6950455ce8] core generic debug: using extension module "lua"
[0000000001c26f48] core interface debug: using interface module "qt4"
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: adding item `Gintama 2017.avi' ( file:///home/darren/Downloads/Gintama%202017/Gintama%202017.avi )
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: processing request item: Gintama 2017.avi, node: null, skip: 0

[...]

[00007f6924c01598] avi stream warning: unknown chunk: �Qw! (not loaded)
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug: </list 'AVI '>
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream warning: unknown chunk: �Qw! (not loaded)
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug: * LIST-root size:838860800 pos:0
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     + RIFF-AVI  size:1564110676 pos:0
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   + LIST-hdrl size:8818 pos:12
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   + avih size:56 pos:24
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   + LIST-strl size:4244 pos:88
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   |   + strh size:56 pos:100
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   |   + strf size:40 pos:164
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   |   + JUNK size:4120 pos:212
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   + LIST-strl size:4222 pos:4340
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   |   + strh size:56 pos:4352
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   |   + strf size:18 pos:4416
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   |   + JUNK size:4120 pos:4442
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   + LIST-odml size:260 pos:8570
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   |   + dmlh size:248 pos:8582
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   + LIST-INFO size:84 pos:8838
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   |   + ISFT size:71 pos:8850
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   + JUNK size:1302 pos:8930
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     |   + �Qw! size:1908644170 pos:10240
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream debug:     + �Qw! size:1908644170 pos:10240
[00007f6924c01808] avi demux error: invalid file: cannot find hdrl or movi chunks
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream warning: unknown chunk: �Qw! (not unloaded)
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream warning: unknown chunk: �Qw! (not unloaded)

[...]

[00007f6924c40a88] core demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
[00007f69300009b8] core input debug: `file:///home/darren/Downloads/Gintama%202017/Gintama%202017.avi' successfully opened
[00007f6924c01808] ps demux warning: garbage at input, trying to resync...
[00007f692c003b58] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f692c003b58] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f692c003b58] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f692c003b58] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f692c003b58] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f692c003b58] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f692c003b58] core art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[00007f692c000a38] core art finder debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f692c000a38] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/darren/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f692c000a38] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f692c000a38] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher/tvrage.luac
[00007f692c000a38] core art finder debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
[00007f692c000a38] core art finder debug: removing module "lua"
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: searching art for Gintama 2017.avi
[00007f692c002c78] core art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
[00007f692c002c78] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/darren/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f692c002c78] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f692c002c78] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f692c002c78] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f692c002c78] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f692c002c78] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f692c002c78] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f692c002c78] core art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: art not found for Gintama 2017.avi
^A^C[0000000001b11098] core libvlc debug: removing all interfaces
[0000000001b11098] core libvlc debug: exiting
[0000000001c26f48] core interface debug: removing module "qt4"
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: deactivating the playlist
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: incoming request - stopping current input
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: finished input
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: incoming request - stopping current input
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: finished input
[00007f6924c01808] core demux debug: removing module "ps"
[00007f6924c01598] core stream debug: removing module "record"
[00007f6924000e58] core access debug: removing module "filesystem"
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: incoming request - stopping current input
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: dead input
[0000000001bec238] core audio output debug: removing module "pulse"
[0000000001c26f48] qt4 interface debug: IM: Deleting the input
[0000000001c26f48] qt4 interface debug: requesting exit...
[0000000001c26f48] qt4 interface debug: waiting for UI thread...
[0000000001b11098] core libvlc debug: exiting
[0000000001c26f48] qt4 interface debug: QApp exec() finished
[0000000001c26f48] qt4 interface debug: Video is not needed anymore
[0000000001c26f48] qt4 interface debug: Killing extension dialog provider
[0000000001c26f48] qt4 interface debug: ExtensionsDialogProvider is quitting...
[00007f6950455ce8] core generic debug: removing module "lua"
[00007f6950455ce8] lua generic debug: Deactivating all loaded extensions
[00007f6950455ce8] lua generic debug: All extensions are now deactivated
[0000000001c1f638] core interface debug: removing module "dbus"
[0000000001c1e668] core interface debug: removing module "xcb_hotkeys"
[0000000001c1dc98] core interface debug: removing module "hotkeys"
[0000000001bf7f68] core playlist debug: destroying
[0000000001c24278] core playlist export debug: saving Media Library to file /home/darren/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf.tmp3640
[0000000001c24278] core playlist export debug: looking for playlist export module matching "export-xspf": 4 candidates
[0000000001c24278] core playlist export debug: using playlist export module "export"
[0000000001c24278] core playlist export debug: removing module "export"
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

[The end of output]
```

Installed codecs

```
$ apt list --installed | grep vlc
libvlc5/
libvlccore8/
vlc/
vlc-data/
vlc-nox/
vlc-plugin-notify/
vlc-plugin-samba/

$ apt list --installed | grep gstream
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/
gstreamer1.0-alsa/
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/
gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3/
gstreamer1.0-libav/
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad/
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers/
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly/
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr/
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/
gstreamer1.0-tools/
gstreamer1.0-x/
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/
libgstreamer1.0-0/
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/
phonon-backend-gstreamer/
phonon-backend-gstreamer-common/

$ apt list --installed | grep avcodec
libavcodec-extra/
libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56/

$ apt list --installed |grep ubuntu-res
ubuntu-restricted-addons/xenial,now 23 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ubuntu-restricted-extras/xenial,now 65 amd64 [installed]
```

`xxd`:

```
$ xxd -a ./Gintama\ 2017.avi |head -n 100
00000000: 5249 4646 546f 3a5d 4156 4920 4c49 5354  RIFFTo:]AVI LIST
00000010: 7222 0000 6864 726c 6176 6968 3800 0000  r"..hdrlavih8...
00000020: eca2 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1001 0000  ................
00000030: 5431 0200 0000 0000 0200 0000 0000 0000  T1..............
00000040: d002 0000 9001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4c49 5354 9410 0000  ........LIST....
00000060: 7374 726c 7374 7268 3800 0000 7669 6473  strlstrh8...vids
00000070: 7876 6964 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  xvid............
00000080: e903 0000 c05d 0000 0000 0000 5431 0200  .....]......T1..
00000090: ce5d 0300 1027 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .]...'..........
000000a0: d002 9001 7374 7266 2800 0000 2800 0000  ....strf(...(...
000000b0: d002 0000 9001 0000 0100 0c00 5856 4944  ............XVID
000000c0: 005e 1a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .^..............
000000d0: 0000 0000 4a55 4e4b 1810 0000 0000 0000  ....JUNK........
000000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
000010f0: 0000 0000 4c49 5354 7e10 0000 7374 726c  ....LIST~...strl
00001100: 7374 7268 3800 0000 6175 6473 0000 0000  strh8...auds....
00001110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000  ................
00001120: c0da 0000 0000 0000 6463 0114 606d 0000  ........dc..`m..
00001130: ffff ffff 0100 0000 6400 6f00 6900 7400  ........d.o.i.t.
00001140: 7374 7266 1200 0000 0020 0600 80bb 0000  strf..... ......
00001150: c0da 0000 0100 0000 0000 4a55 4e4b 1810  ..........JUNK..
00001160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
00002170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 4c49 5354 0401  ..........LIST..
00002180: 0000 6f64 6d6c 646d 6c68 f800 0000 5431  ..odmldmlh....T1
00002190: 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000021a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
00002280: 0000 0000 0000 4c49 5354 5400 0000 494e  ......LISTT...IN
00002290: 464f 4953 4654 4700 0000 5669 7274 7561  FOISFTG...Virtua
000022a0: 6c44 7562 4d6f 6420 312e 352e 3130 2e33  lDubMod 1.5.10.3
000022b0: 207c 2077 7777 2e76 6972 7475 616c 6475   | www.virtualdu
000022c0: 622d 6672 2e6f 7267 207c 7c20 2862 7569  b-fr.org || (bui
000022d0: 6c64 2032 3535 302f 7265 6c65 6173 6529  ld 2550/release)
000022e0: 0000 4a55 4e4b 1605 0000 5669 7274 7561  ..JUNK....Virtua
000022f0: 6c44 7562 4d6f 6420 6275 696c 6420 3235  lDubMod build 25
00002300: 3530 2f72 656c 6561 7365 0000 0000 0000  50/release......
00002310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
00002800: aa51 7721 4a99 c371 ef9c b9f1 8f0a b57c  .Qw!J..q.......|
00002810: d881 155e 5814 7d03 2c07 b2cb 2e54 5562  ...^X.}.,....TUb
00002820: 946e b464 ee89 8075 6885 2dae 2671 f863  .n.d...uh.-.&q.c
00002830: 6dbf 0c6d b7e1 8db6 fc0e 6db7 a23f a23e  m..m......m..?.>
00002840: 1cdb 6fdf 7c78 2344 b831 b6df b828 bc7e  ..o.|x#D.1...(.~
00002850: 79f1 fbc0 cea8 6403 83d4 a3c2 fcfa 6f6b  y.....d.......ok
00002860: 3d5b ec64 ba39 f219 c92d ec47 2a0a 487d  =[.d.9...-.G*.H}
00002870: 9869 bfb1 b3fe ddcd c5e6 e5b2 ca49 5c5d  .i...........I\]
00002880: 9d87 8dcb ce52 603e 15da 1f6a a56d 3732  .....R`>...j.m72
00002890: e55f 3f93 db95 47f0 ae2f 8865 3434 962d  ._?...G../.e44.-
000028a0: 0db5 c1a9 5b7f 0820 c5a3 7078 9ffb 40d8  ....[.. ..px..@.
000028b0: 3c6f ff2a 425d 9796 c815 98d5 a2a2 95c8  <o.*B]..........
000028c0: 4bc7 81fd 9614 3dca 3372 5314 49db d14e  K.....=.3rS.I..N
000028d0: bc14 6ef8 3502 76b1 29dd 28a1 b9f0 51eb  ..n.5.v.).(...Q.
000028e0: 0d00 9df1 ff65 1378 bd3c acb7 f965 e94c  .....e.x.<...e.L
000028f0: 20fa 350f b0a5 8515 b04e faef 026d b584   .5......N...m..
00002900: ecf3 173f d713 0134 d713 3f06 ac28 fec1  ...?...4..?..(..
00002910: 3877 6c91 6a48 fdd3 30d6 7dbb bbec 436d  8wl.jH..0.}...Cm
00002920: 84fe 03b6 e5e7 4070 2c4f 347c 01fc 0952  ......@p,O4|...R
00002930: f7b0 55f5 c95d 81e1 8513 b9db 8b0c 7781  ..U..]........w.
00002940: 2bed 4ed4 450f e3b1 a01f aeb9 8389 0079  +.N.E..........y
00002950: eacb 6a21 3d29 82a9 429c 6a1e ba3e 00fe  ..j!=)..B.j..>..
00002960: 00f3 cfde 5884 54ef 051e 04cb 7f65 15bb  ....X.T......e..
00002970: 051e 7c09 09b0 9dde 8a9f 7828 0a78 3c07  ..|.......x(.x<.
00002980: eabb 1321 703c 07ec 6ac7 e3e8 a651 f974  ...!p<..j....Q.t
00002990: aa2f 07be d688 c100 7aac 0cfc 08fc 5a01  ./......z.....Z.
000029a0: 85dd 12d5 2e3d 549d 90c8 7d07 c4a1 041b  .....=T...}.....
000029b0: 40b2 e640 d835 c1e0 3f85 061e 8960 c941  @..@.5..?....`.A
000029c0: 9b1e b65f cf30 3a56 ac78 5c9b dbb5 a61a  ..._.0:V.x\.....
000029d0: 54cf fca5 746d b762 9fef 2756 88a3 8280  T...tm.b..'V....
000029e0: 3c04 1ba0 c3c2 e2f6 c760 c94b e67f 478c  <........`.K..G.
000029f0: d1e0 f32a f1a6 efa7 d5ab b2ce 299e dccf  ...*........)...
00002a00: 5473 bb67 1e22 80f0 1050 8960 df06 03a0  Ts.g."...P.`....
00002a10: cad5 6330 7c07 87c1 053d 6c4b 1c29 9bf6  ..c0|....=lK.)..
00002a20: 5427 a993 7b6c 2d6f d19e 7f6d 2cf7 175e  T'..{l-o...m,..^
00002a30: 9e09 20c1 0818 461f 0304 2051 3610 07c9  .. ...F... Q6...
00002a40: fe5f 9f6d 3a5f a7ff 9af7 dbfb 79c9 d8d5  ._.m:_......y...
00002a50: b9cc cc99 2ca4 483f 4ad3 03ac 54c6 c9fb  ....,.H?J...T...
00002a60: ef76 6445 9abe f6a0 b46a 70f0 7ccb 225d  .vmadE.....jp.|."]
00002a70: 56af 2df4 6ffc bb62 fb2d 99c8 8641 a01b  V.-.o..b.-...A..
00002a80: 0822 1021 d1d8 929d 35cf 4614 6d62 f17b  .".!....5.F.mb.{
00002a90: 3d79 54f6 aea6 2f24 8b1e 3a0c ac77 ac8f  =yT.../$..:..w..
00002aa0: 4112 6818 4d22 c82b 7b3b b692 c9c9 0987  A.h.M".+{;......
00002ab0: d9bb edcf fb6e 6e72 cdcb cb2f 1058 bb9d  .....nnr.../.X..
00002ac0: b76d bb6d b6f6 db7b 6d37 6908 6d74 e02c  .m.m...{m7i.mt.,
00002ad0: b025 79a5 78ce 7393 d248 854a 2ba1 88a4  .%y.x.s..H.J+...
00002ae0: 0da4 0c3a 5544 14e9 5066 6350 d5b6 cda3  ...:UD..PfcP....
00002af0: 0920 d500 6560 c230 30fc 7a08 2086 21e0  . ..e`.00.z. .!.
00002b00: 3780 ee2a 5624 8f52 cda5 dbbc 6b59 fecb  7..*V$.R....kY..
00002b10: dcef 6285 fb08 04c2 1043 1284 a081 e033  ..b......C.....3
00002b20: 2b25 7bf6 a4b1 bd6e a045 c939 c936 de1e  +%{....n.E.9.6..
00002b30: 0529 7033 65e9 476a 98c4 cd16 37f9 e519  .)p3e.Gj....7...
00002b40: 754c 96af aa7a 224e db39 c384 8943 da3e  uL...z"N.9...C.>
00002b50: bb66 4d53 24bd b672 77a4 03e0 7421 3610  .fMS$..rw...t!6.
00002b60: 5b6e 95fb 18db cb64 9d51 9c11 7852 700d  [n.....d.Q..xRp.
00002b70: 860a b235 b9d9 7ab7 2a25 fa89 758e 9612  ...5..z.*%..u...
00002b80: 0100 2084 1d98 2408 c3d1 eddd 992a 648d  .. ...$......*d.
00002b90: b78a 6a28 a731 44e8 a4d0 960f 0103 c830  ..j(.1D........0
00002ba0: 85e0 50ab 0664 4b1f 31ad b333 a99b 9015  ..P..dK.1..3....
```

Comment: Have you considered that movie files from pirated torrent sites may be garbage data?

Comment: Thans for your suggestion. But (as a kind of research or just out of curiosity) is there any way to prove it? E.g. the binary data is self-repeating...

Comment: The last line of vlc's output isn't sufficient?

Comment: everything after "resync..." is pasted

Comment: I have found that the updated ffmpeg will not play many older avi formats. Xvid is a variant of avi.

Comment: So what? Vlc still says "garbage at input".

Comment: perhaps it is garbage, or perhaps it just can't read an outdated codec. I had to convert many avi files using openshot because vlc would not play them

Comment: I noticed a line in the middle of the VLC output "avi demux error: invalid file: cannot find hdrl or movi chunks"  that seems to indicate that the file is not in good shape.

Comment: @ravery did VLC say the input read was garbage in those cases?

Comment: After download  completes, there is a "xvid-codec-installer.exe" together with the Gintama\ 2017.avi in the folder. I uploaded the exe to 3 online virus scan sites and a bunch of trojan/backdoor/...s are reported. Now I'm convinced That the whole thing is a fraud. Am I supposed to delete this question? (newbie)

Comment: @muru -- I used vlc via GUI, it doesn't say anything. with the change from libav to ffmpeg, it would crash or play distorted video unless specific output settings were used. With the update to ffmpeg it only crashes no way to play them at all .... however openshot played them perfectly though warned of an old outdated codec. half of my avi files had to be converted so that vlc would play them

Comment: @EliahKagan Post a clarified answer please. I'll take it as an example and try to learn something from it.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `ffprobe 'Gintama 2017.avi'` and `ffmpeg -i 'Gintama 2017.avi' -c copy -f matroska 'Gintama 2017.mkv' && ffprobe 'Gintama 2017.mkv'`? Thanks.

Comment: Darren Wu, If you still have the file, I'd encourage you to try [the commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962760/whats-wrong-when-vlc-says-cannot-find-hdrl-or-movi-chunks#comment1541113_962760) that @DavidFoerster has suggested and add the output to your question. I don't think my answer has really missed anything, and I don't agree with this question being closed, but running those commands shouldn't hurt anything and may be interesting.

Comment: @DavidFoerster FFprobe b4 and after conversion are added.

Comment: Thanks. FFmpeg found *something* or at least it thinks it did. However, as you can see the duration of the remultiplexed streams are only 6 minutes as opposed to 53 in the originals and the video pixel format is invalid. This is in line with the answer of @EliahKagan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### VLC doesn't think the file contains anything that can be played.

As muru [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962760/vlc-xvid-avi-video-play-failure?noredirect=1#comment1539861_962760), `vlc` told you:

```
[00007f6924c01808] ps demux warning: garbage at input, trying to resync...
```

None of the previous or subsequent output was particularly encouraging or suggested that you had a real, working video file, either. The [`file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/file.1.html) command usually only looks at or near the beginning of a file to guess its type, and `vlc` was able to *try* to play the file, but it wasn't able to find anything in it that it could play, nor even anything that *looked* like it could be played if you had more codecs installed.

The "trying to resync" part might have led to better results if the problem was that the file was not being properly read, but it wasn't.

### This looks like it's *not* an AVI file at all, rather than needing codecs.

Before concluding that the data it was given were garbage, `vlc` had shown you messages like this:

```
[00007f6924c01598] avi stream warning: unknown chunk: �Qw! (not loaded)
```

Then, as [Charles Green mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962760/vlc-xvid-avi-video-play-failure?noredirect=1#comment1540012_962760), it told you:

```
[00007f6924c01808] avi demux error: invalid file: cannot find hdrl or movi chunks
```

If this were a real AVI file and the problem were just that you needed codecs, then VLC should still have been able to find the *hdrl* and *movi* data. It would then have failed later, when it actually tried to play the file. You might have had audio without video, video without audio, or even neither, but this would have happened when it tried to interpret the *movi* data in the file.

The United States Library of Congress [explains what *hdrl* and *movi* are all about](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000059.shtml):

> The first subchunk is tagged as *hdrl* and plays the role of file
>   header, providing metadata about the video, such as width, height and
>   frame rate. The second subchunk is tagged *movi* and it carries the
>   actual picture and sound data, which may employ a wide range of
>   codecs...

Rather than being unable to decode video or audio data in the file, VLC didn't even find metadata to tell it where any of those data were. So this file was either *(a)* never an AVI file to begin with, or *(b)* corrupted. If you obtained the file via BitTorrent, that's usually pretty good at preventing transmission errors (because each piece's hash is checked), so it was likely either corrupted before you downloaded it, or it was never intended to be a real AVI file.

### Other Possibilities

*Technically* there are some other possibilities. If you had prior reason to think that the file was good, then I would suggest that it might be:

- Corrupted even though you used a protocol (BitTorrent) that usually prevents corruption. Most BitTorrent programs have a "force recheck" feature that lets you double check that all pieces received are hashed correctly.
- A file you needed codecs for *that was also wrongly named `.avi`* when it was actually a different container filetype. That would still be unlikely, though, because when you looked at the *top* of the file (which the `file` command looked at) it still appeared to be an AVI.
- Produced by a program that was meant to produce an actual AVI file but had serious bugs causing the format to be wrong, but playable with *some* other players that happened to tolerate the wrong format (perhaps due to bugs of their own). I think this is the least likely possibility, though you could try opening the file in a video editor like [OpenShot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShot) as [ravery suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962760/vlc-xvid-avi-video-play-failure?noredirect=1#comment1540322_962760).

In this case, you have a powerful heuristic to support the explanation that the file was deliberately fake: it [came with an executable file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962760/vlc-xvid-avi-video-play-failure?noredirect=1#comment1540233_962760) (for Windows) that claimed to be an installer for codecs the file needed, which was accompanied by no documentation whatsoever, and *multiple* malware scanners told you that file appeared to be malware.

> Now I'm convinced That the whole thing is a fraud.

Yes, that is the overwhelmingly most likely explanation.